# No such property: sonatypeUserName for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-extensions

I'm trying to use this blibioteca [android-maps-extensions](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions) because I need to fix more than 1000 markers on my map .

Added the project dependencies in my project :

```
compile project (':android-maps-extensions')
```

But when I update build.gradle get the following error :

> No such property : for class sonatypeUserName :
>   org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

The username and password appear to be incorrect or something , this code is part of the project I'm build.gradle matter how library:

```
...

pom.project {
    name 'Android Maps Extensions'
    description 'Library extending capabilities of Google Maps Android API v2'
    inceptionYear '2013'
    url 'http://AndroidMapsExtensions.com'
    packaging 'aar'

    developers {
        developer {
            name 'Maciej Górski'
            id 'mg6maciej'
            email 'maciek.gorski@gmail.com'
            url 'http://mg6.pl'
        }
    }

    licenses {
        license {
            name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
            url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
            distribution 'repo'
       }
    }

    scm {
        url 'https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions'
        connection 'scm:git:https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions.git'
        developerConnection 'scm:git:https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions.git'
        }
    }

...
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 24):

Open the `gradle.properties` file inside the projects `android-maps-utils-master` that you may have downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

You will find

```
version=0.4-SNAPSHOT

# variables required to allow build.gradle to parse,
# override in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
signing.keyId=
signing.password=
signing.secretKeyRingFile=

sonatypeUsername=
sonatypePassword=
```

inside it, just copy and put it in your projects `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 9):

modify your gradle.properties file:

```
#To fix compile error. 
sonatypeRepo=null  
sonatypeUsername=null  
sonatypePassword=null
```

Comment: I didn't have a `gradle.properties` file, the solution was to create it with these contents in the project's root folder.

Answer (score 1):

When using gradle, you don't normally copy the project into your own, but instead just add dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    // your other dependencies
    compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.1.+';
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.+'
}
```

To see the latest versions of libraries, you may use [Gradle, please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/).

But if you want to use the project directly, you also need to have [gradle.properties](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions/blob/develop/gradle.properties) with variables defined:

```
sonatypeUserName=
sonatypePassword=
```

Answer (score 1):

**I believe This line shows error**:

authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)

**Replace it with**:

authentication(userName: hasProperty('ossrhUsername')?ossrhUsername:'', password: hasProperty('ossrhPassword')?ossrhPassword:'')

Answer (score 0):

Also, if other suggestions didn't fix the problem, you can try to re-write your lib's `build.gradle`  as usual `build.gradle` file. More likely its not a good idea, but it worked for me properly:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

version = "1.0.1"
group = "com.edmodo"

android {

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error

> No such property : for class sonatypeUserName : org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

What I did to fix the problem was I just copy pasted 'sonatypeUserName' in the `gradle.properties`