# Importing library gives error in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to `Android Studio`. I am trying to work using the `android-map-utils` library. But it is giving me the following error.

```
 `Error:(64) A problem occurred evaluating project ':library'.
  > No such property: sonatypeUsername for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated`
```

Can anyone help me with this issue and also tell me a easy way to import libraries in android studio?

Comment: check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem while I was migrating from eclipse. I resolved my issue by using the gradle method of including the library (as opposed to importing it as a module and using it as a dependency).

> Add the following dependency to your Gradle build file:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
> }
> ```

source: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/#start

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to comment.

Applying gradle dependency as link doesn't allow us to view it's source properly.

So if you are interested in viewing source too, in Android Studio itself

> You should try adding library as a module project, i.e.,
>
> File -> New -> Import Module -> (Dir of Library)

after importing, you'll face an error, which can be resolved from - [Adding Maps Utils Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714706/no-such-property-sonatypeusername-for-class-org-gradle-api-publication-maven-i#28322749)