# No such property: whisperSonatypeUsername

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to make path/gradle libaxolotl/android to [this project](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/libaxolotl-java) but I get the following error:

```
 No such property: whisperSonatypeUsername for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer
```

I'm trying to fix this using [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714706/no-such-property-sonatypeusername-for-class-org-gradle-api-publication-maven-i)

> modify your gradle.properties file:

```
#To fix compile error. 
sonatypeRepo=null  
sonatypeUsername=null  
sonatypePassword=null
```

But I get the same error. I'm using Ubuntu 14 and I do not used the gradle version of the repositories of ubuntu, instead I download the latest version. Maybe fot that, the above solution doesnot work for me. Could you help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No such property: sonatypeUserName for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714706/no-such-property-sonatypeusername-for-class-org-gradle-api-publication-maven-i)

Comment: @Simon is not duplicated I'm trying that solution but that doesnot work for me I trying to explain this in my above question "I'm trying to fix this using this suggestion"