# Could not get unknown property 'sonatypeRepo'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Just cloned a project https://github.com/obolsh/RAMBooster.

I have updated class path to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

I have added `google()` to `buildScript` & `allProjects` tag.

I have updated gradle wrapper version to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

I have updated its compileSdkVersion, min, target as well.

But i am getting this weird error, i could not find a solution for me. I found a same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22714706/6891563) on SO. but that did not help me.

> Could not get unknown property 'sonatypeRepo' for object of type
>   org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer.

Can some one tell why this issue raise and what is the solution?

Comment: Why do you need to clone the project? If you want to use the library, it's `compile 'com.github.obolsh:rambooster:1.0.2@aar'`

Comment: It is 3 years old project, i need to update it.

Comment: But anyway, upgrading Gradle should be done with caution on a 3 year old repo. Types get deprecated and removed, and that error exists in here https://github.com/obolsh/RAMBooster/blob/master/rambooster/build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it by removing unused tags in gradle for me. `uploadArchives`, `signing` & `configurations` in [this build.gradle](https://github.com/obolsh/RAMBooster/blob/master/rambooster/build.gradle)